# does paypal provide services for getting sales tax w.r.t zip code for US?

Tags: api, paypal, postal-code, sales-tax

I am using paypal for my payments, i wanted to include the tax thing w.r.t zip code. like when customer enters the zip code i could get the sales tax percentage w.r.t that zip code. I believe there will be any way of it in paypal but unfortunately i couldn't find that. kindly guide me in this regard, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 3rd party service like http://zip2tax.com/

I think there is also a service on Paypal where you can input the zip code range or US State and tax amount for that area, (but I think it only works with paid Paypal account Website Payments Pro).

Also have a look at: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_ProfileAndTools#id08A9ED00LTU

Comment: Thanks for answering.. but i already used the first option after going through many searches for paypal..